# How to create relational database and make it accessible by all devices in android

Tags: android

so i am a bit new to android and was wondering if it is possible to implement the following in an android app:

1. Is it possible to create an android relational database online that my app or any device with app can access?

   -If yes, where will the database be stored/hosted?(maybe amazon s3 or simpleDB)

   -and how can the data be stored, accessed?
2. What other alternatives are there to share relational data between android devices?
3. Would this cause the app to run slowly as i might be running many relational queries per request?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an MySQL database and use the mysql database connector lib for Java.

connector: http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html

Comment: Thanks for the links, however where would you host the database so that i can access it from any android device?

Comment: For that you have to search online for services that provide that. You could try here: http://www.freemysql.net/

Comment: It would probably be best to run it locally on your PC while developing. Then you can connect to it by using the IP address of your pc